# Do filtergraphs copy audio streams by default in FFMpeg?

Tags: bash, audio, video, ffmpeg

I 've got the following command in FFMpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i file_input.mp4 -filter_complex split=2[i1][i2];[i1]scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480[o1];[i2]scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:640[o2] -map [o1] -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 file_out_1.mp4 -map [o2] -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 file_out_2.mp4
```

What this command does is to essentially split my source file in two, scale the video in 2 different forms and re-encode the video streams using the `x264` codec. So far so good.

Now please notice the `-map 0:a` flag. If I remove this from either of the two streams, the resulting output file will have no audio at all. This makes me wonder whether the `scale` filter automatically removes the audio from the bouquet or is it something else.

If I slightly change the command to this and attempt to fetch the audio stream from the resulting [o1] or [o2] I still can't get no sound:

```
ffmpeg -i eFront_sample.mp4 -filter_complex split=2[i1][i2];[i1]scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480[o1];[i2]scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:640[o2] -map [o1]:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 file_out_1.mp4 -map [o2]:a -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec libx264 file_out_2.mp4
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Steam selection

By default one stream per stream type will be selected. If you use `-map` then this default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior will be disabled.

However, it is generally recommended to explicitly define your filter inputs and outputs instead of relying on the defaults to avoid unexpected stream selection issues.

## Scale

Instead of `trunc(oh*a/2)*2` you could probably just use `-2`. From the scale video filter documentation:

> If one of the values is -n with n > 1, the scale filter will also use
>   a value that maintains the aspect ratio of the input image, calculated
>   from the other specified dimension. After that it will, however, make
>   sure that the calculated dimension is divisible by n and adjust the
>   value if necessary.

x264 requires that the width and height be divisible by 2 when outputting yuv420p, so the `-2` will deal with that assuming your declared value is acceptable.

## Example

Your resulting command could then look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=2[i1][i2]; \
 [i1]scale=-2:480,format=yuv420p[o1]; \
 [i2]scale=-2:640,format=yuv420p[o2]" \
-map "[o1]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 output1.mp4 \
-map "[o2]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 output2.mp4
```